# Button to remove row of table is not working using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

This is the table in which I have used button to remove of table.

```
    <table>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Middle Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>User Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Remove</th>

            </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Sujan6</td>
                    <td>Bikram5</td>
                    <td>Thapa</td>
                    <td>Sujan6</td>
                    <td>Sujan@gmail5</td>
                    <td><button class="button button3"><a href="/Home/StudentList/54">Remove</a></button></td>
                </tr>
<tr>
            <td>Sujan7</td>
            <td>Bikram6</td>
            <td>Thapa</td>
            <td>Sujan7</td>
            <td>Sujan@gmail5</td>
            <td><button class="button button3"><a href="/Home/StudentList/55">Remove</a></button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

This is the Javascript code with which I am trying to remove row of table. This code show error of:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined" at the line of " var tr = td.target.parentElement;"

```
var deleteRecord = document.getElementsByClassName('button button3');
for (var i = 0; i < deleteRecord.length; i++) {
    deleteRecord[i].addEventListener('click', removeItem);

}
function removeItem(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (confirm('Are You Sure')) {
        var td = e.target.parentElement;
        var tr = td.target.parentElement;
        tr.parentElement.removeChild('tr');
    }
}
```

Comment: at the line `tr = td.target.parentElement;`, `td` is a `node`, not an `event`, so it doesn't have a `target` attribute. just do  `td.parentElement`

Answer (score 0):

`td` is not an event, so it doesn't have a target. Accessing this will cause the error you are seeing. Access the `parentElement` directly on `td`.

You also need to remove the quotes around `tr` when removing the element.

```
function removeItem(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (confirm('Are You Sure')) {
        var td = e.target.parentElement;
        var tr = td.parentElement;
        tr.parentElement.removeChild(tr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It still showed error in last line "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'". So i changed removeChild(tr) to remove(tr). and it worked. Thanks for your help. @ItsPete